# setState function not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to ReactJS and am trying to modify values of a form which is populated by the response of an API call. I want to be able to modify the principals received in every row and get their sum in another field. The `onChange` handler function is :

```
handleAmortScheduleChange(field , key ,e  ){
            const value = e.target.value;

            this.setState({
            [get_schedule[key][field]] : value,
            [get_emi_amount]:get_schedule[key]["principal"] + get_schedule[key]["interest"],
            [get_schedule[key]["closing_balance"]] : get_schedule[key]["starting_balance"] - get_emi_amount

           });                         
            var arr = document.getElementsByName('get_schedule_principal_here');
            var tot=0;
            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

                if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
            }
            document.getElementById('get_total_principal').value = tot;

        }
```

The JSX Code is:

```
{this.state.get_schedule.map((row,key) =>

<div key={key} className="row aaaa">

    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input ref = "get_schedule_emi_date" type="date" required="required" id="get_schedule_emi_date"  value={row.date} />
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">EMI Date</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input ref = "get_schedule_emi_amount" type="number" required="required" id="get_schedule_emi_amount"  value={row.amount}/>
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">EMI Amount</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input ref = "get_schedule_principal" type="number" required="required" id="get_schedule_principal" name="get_schedule_principal_here" value={row.principal} onChange={this.handleAmortScheduleChange.bind(this, "principal",key)}/>
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">Principal</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input ref = "get_schedule_interest" type="number" required="required" id="get_schedule_interest"   value={row.interest} onChange={this.handleAmortScheduleChange.bind(this, "principal",key)} />
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">Interest</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input ref = "get_schedule_starting_balance" type="number" required="required" id="get_schedule_starting_balance"  value={row.starting_balance }/>
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">Starting Balance</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>
    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input ref = "get_schedule_closing_balance" type="number" required="required" id="get_schedule_closing_balance"  value={row.closing_balance}/>
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">Closing Balance</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>

</div>)}
<div className="row">
    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input  type="number" required="required" id="get_total_principal" />
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">Total Principal</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>

    <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <input  type="number" required="required" id="get_total_interest" />
        <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">Total Interest</label><i className="getAmort-bar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

`get_schedule` is an array of arrays in the response of the API containing values for all the fields in the form. I am essentially trying to change the values for the principal and interest as entered by the user and set their respective values in the get_schedule array.

The error that I am getting in the `handleAmortScheduleChange` function   is
`Uncaught ReferenceError: get_schedule is not defined`. I am unable to set the state for interest or principal either. Where am I going wrong and what would be the solution to this?

EDIT 1: As requested, the definition of get_schedule and some other parameters in the component class.

```
class LoanDetails extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        this.state={
            get_schedule            : [],
            get_interest            : 0,
            get_principal           : 0,
            get_starting_balance    : 0,
            get_closing_balance     : 0,
            get_emi_date            : 0,
            get_emi_amount          : 0,
     }
}
```

The value set to get_schedule from the API response is :

```
get_schedule: [{discount: 0, amount: 501, starting_balance: 1000, interest: 1, date: "2019-01-06",…},…]
0: {discount: 0, amount: 501, starting_balance: 1000, interest: 1, date: "2019-01-06",…}
amount: 501
closing_balance: 500
date: "2019-01-06"
discount: 0
interest: 1
principal: 500
starting_balance: 1000
1: {discount: 0, amount: 501, starting_balance: 500, interest: 1, date: "2019-02-06", closing_balance: 0,…}
amount: 501
closing_balance: 0
date: "2019-02-06"
discount: 0
interest: 1
principal: 500
starting_balance: 500
```

Comment: Where / how is `get_schedule` defined?  You probably want to access it as a property.

Comment: add all your component code please

Comment: The problem is what the error reports, `get_schedule` is not defined.

Comment: @SLaks I have added the code.

Comment: Your constructor code doesn't do anything (those are labelled empty statements, not assignments).

Comment: I had forgotten to add this.state. I have edited the above code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made some changes and got my code to work.

```
  class Loan extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      field: "",
      get_schedule: [
        {
          amount: 2000,
          principal: 0,
          discount: 0,
          date: "2019-01-06",
          interest: 0,
          starting_balance: 1000,
          closing_balance: 0
        },
        {
          amount: 3000,
          principal: 0,
          discount: 0,
          date: "2019-02-06",
          interest: 0,
          starting_balance: 1500,
          closing_balance: 0
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  handleAmortScheduleChange = (key, field) => e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const { get_schedule, get_emi_amount } = this.state;
    const old_schedule = get_schedule[key];
    const new_get_schedule = [...get_schedule];
    new_get_schedule[key] = {
      ...old_schedule,
      [field]: value,
      closing_balance: old_schedule.starting_balance - get_emi_amount
    };
    this.setState({
      get_schedule: new_get_schedule,
      get_emi_amount: old_schedule.principal + old_schedule.interest
      // [get_schedule[key][field]]: value,
      // [get_emi_amount]: get_schedule[key]["principal"] + get_schedule[key]["interest"],
      // [get_schedule[key]["closing_balance"]]: get_schedule[key]["starting_balance"] - get_emi_amount,
    });
    var arr = document.getElementsByName("get_schedule_principal_here");
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(arr[i].value)) tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("get_total_principal").value = tot;
  };

  render() {
    const { get_schedule, get_emi_amount } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.get_schedule.map((row, key) => (
          <div key={key} className="row aaaa">
            <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <input
                ref="get_schedule_emi_date"
                type="date"
                required="required"
                id="get_schedule_emi_date"
                value={row.date}
              />
              <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
                EMI Date
              </label>
              <i className="getAmort-bar" />
            </div>
            <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <input
                ref="get_schedule_emi_amount"
                type="number"
                required="required"
                id="get_schedule_emi_amount"
                value={get_schedule[key].amount}
              />
              <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
                EMI Amount
              </label>
              <i className="getAmort-bar" />
            </div>
            <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <input
                ref="get_schedule_principal"
                type="number"
                required="required"
                id="get_schedule_principal"
                name="get_schedule_principal_here"
                value={get_schedule[key].principal}
                onChange={this.handleAmortScheduleChange(key, "principal")}
              />
              <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
                Principal
              </label>
              <i className="getAmort-bar" />
            </div>
            <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <input
                ref="get_schedule_interest"
                type="number"
                required="required"
                id="get_schedule_interest"
                value={get_schedule[key].interest}
                onChange={this.handleAmortScheduleChange(key, "interest")}
              />
              <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
                Interest
              </label>
              <i className="getAmort-bar" />
            </div>
            <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <input
                ref="get_schedule_starting_balance"
                type="number"
                required="required"
                id="get_schedule_starting_balance"
                value={row.starting_balance}
              />
              <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
                Starting Balance
              </label>
              <i className="getAmort-bar" />
            </div>
            <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
              <input
                ref="get_schedule_closing_balance"
                type="number"
                required="required"
                id="get_schedule_closing_balance"
                value={get_schedule[key].closing_balance}
              />
              <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
                Closing Balance
              </label>
              <i className="getAmort-bar" />
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <div className="row">
          <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <input type="number" required="required" id="get_total_principal" />
            <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
              Total Principal
            </label>
            <i className="getAmort-bar" />
          </div>

          <div className="getAmort-form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <input type="number" required="required" id="get_total_interest" />
            <label for="input" className="getAmort-control-label">
              Total Interest
            </label>
            <i className="getAmort-bar" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the error is `setState` is not defined, You lose the this context. could you be able to try arrow functions for your `handleAmortScheduleChange` function ?

```
    handleAmortScheduleChange = (field , key ,e  ) => {
        const value = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
        [get_schedule[key][field]] : value,
        [get_emi_amount]:get_schedule[key]["principal"] + get_schedule[key]["interest"],
        [get_schedule[key]["closing_balance"]] : get_schedule[key]["starting_balance"] - get_emi_amount

       });                         
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('get_schedule_principal_here');
        console.log(arr.length);
        console.log(arr);
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
                console.log(tot);
        }
        document.getElementById('get_total_principal').value = tot;

    }
```

If the error is `get_schedule` is not defined is maybe because you perform async operation and by the time that it gets to render function it's undefined I highly suggest to check the flow of your code. If you put more code I can give you more clue but meanwhile try below syntax.

```
// double check if get_schedule is ready to use
{this.state.get_schedule && this.state.get_schedule.map((row,key) =>

    {
       /*  now map the row and key to inputs */
    }

}
```

For resolving `get_schedule` error in get_schedule would you be able to change your function to arrow function and use `this.get_schedule`

```
handleAmortScheduleChange = (field , key ,e  ) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
    [this.get_schedule[key][field]] : value,
    [get_emi_amount]:this.get_schedule[key]["principal"] + this.get_schedule[key]["interest"],
    [this.get_schedule[key]["closing_balance"]] : this.get_schedule[key]["starting_balance"] - get_emi_amount

   });                         
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('get_schedule_principal_here');
    console.log(arr.length);
    console.log(arr);
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
            console.log(tot);
    }
    document.getElementById('get_total_principal').value = tot;

}
```

I fixed your Sandbox version of your code and you can find it here.

Things that I fixed are these ones:

1. For labels in react use `htmlFor` instead of plain `for`
2. some of your input did not have `onChangeHandler` I just left some onchange handler to resolve the error but make sure you fill the handler of the following input in the way you like them. (EMI_Date, EMI_Amount, CLOSING and START Balance onchange for inputs) ...
3. **the main error** I used different approach of setting state.

Usually if the update you want to do on state is dependent on the current state we use the below syntax as it is safer :)

```
 this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1
    }));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/o4k6nmr4l5

Let me know what you think? there is no error but I don't know anything about calculations of that form :)

Comment: I used your solution but I am getting `Syntax Error : Unexpected token` error under the first `=` sign in the `handleAmortScheduleChange = (field , key ,e  ) => {` line.

Comment: are you using react 16? what's your react version?

Comment: when any state will be setState in any function, the function must be bind in the constructor or an event handler.

Comment: by using arrow function there is no need to bind it anymore - it's ES7 feature, binding has performance issues...

Comment: I am using React 15.6.2

Comment: @Mansour I modified my code according to your suggestions but the error persisted. I even tried binding the `handleAmortScheduleChange`  function.

Comment: I would like to help more - it would be great if you could reproduce it in https://codesandbox.io/s/new and put the link here, I will see and fix it. You don't have to make the ajax call, simply put your data in there just to reproduce the error...

Comment: The get_schedule error is resolved but I am getting another error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined" at             `[this.get_schedule[key][field]] : value,` line when I cahnage the Principal or the Interest amount in the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185392/discussion-between-mansour-and-ajay-singh).

Answer (score 1):

you must bind it in constructor :

```
this.handleAmortScheduleChange = this.handleAmortScheduleChange.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you already have defined get_schedule function, the problem that i see is that your are not calling it using the word this.

You should do something like

`this.get_schedule`